# 'é' is getting converted to 'Ã©' while submitting data from jsp to servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I have a page where username will be retrieved from a db and displayed in a jsp page. This username contains a French character `é` and is displayed fine. But when I submit the user details form in the jsp, this character is converted to `Ã©` in my servlet. I have put alerts in javascript and saw that the value is correct before form submission, so I suspect that something went wrong in between the form submission and value retrieval.

Comment: This looks like the similar issue, But no one has given working solution to that question either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case where you try to convert `UTF-8` content into `ISO-8859-1` as you can see with this simple code:

```
System.out.println(new String("é".getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1"));
```

**Output:**

```
Ã©
```

Make sure that you used `UTF-8` everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the encoding to be the same as the submitted one.
This will most likely be utf8. Should this be the case already check your server's locale settings for encoding as well.